# Pycharm and sys.argv[1]

Tags: python, pycharm, tweets

I'm trying to run in Pycharm this programm :

```
# Chap02-03/twitter_hashtag_frequency.py
import sys
from collections import Counter
import json

def get_hashtags(tweet):
    entities = tweet.get('entities', {})
    hashtags = entities.get('hashtags', [])
    return [tag['text'].lower() for tag in hashtags]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fname = sys.argv[1]
    with open(fname, 'r') as f:
        hashtags = Counter()
        for line in f:
            tweet = json.loads(line)
            hashtags_in_tweet = get_hashtags(tweet)
            hashtags.update(hashtags_in_tweet)
        for tag, count in hashtags.most_common(20):
            print("{}: {}".format(tag, count))
```

I want to run the programm `twitter_hashtag_frequency.py` in Pycharm using a json file `stream_.jsonl` as a parameter, this file is in the same directory as the programm. Can you show me how can I edit this code ? I tried several time, I did'nt succeed, I got this error :

```
 fname = sys.argv[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you run the file by pressing the green play button (next to Edit Configurations), you'll need to specify the argument in the configurations menu in Parameters. Enter `stream_.jsonl` in the text box.

Also double check that the working directory is set to the one containing both these files

[image]

Comment: I use Pycharm Professional 2019.3, in configuration Windows on Script path I have this C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\Bonzanini_Book_Exercises\twitter_hashtag_frequency.py, on Parameters I put "stream_.jsonl" and on my working directory, I have : C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\Bonzanini_Book_Exercises. I still have errors

Comment: What's the error? Can you post a screenshot of your configuration?

Comment: This is the screenshot! [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xqhwu.png

Comment: This is the error! [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fS78t.png

Comment: Can you share the contents of the .jsonl file? A screenshot of the first few lines works

Comment: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ag_QYwEqxuOwiHuBuMTITm9qbYFZ?e=t1zOwf

Comment: Could you share a screenshot? For security reasons I can't download the file and my VM isnt firing up for some reason sigh

Comment: The screenshot of the json file ? If it is that, I can't take a screenshot of it. This file is an output of streaming tweet and is big (4629 ligne), some lines are also long. Can you give me your adress email in order to send you it?